# Cursor Index Out of Bounds Exception: Index -1 requested with size 0

Tags: android, sqlite, exception, cursor

I am just trying to search for the data in multiple table.If the where condition data is not present in first table(tab1) then it has to search in the second table(tab2) but I am getting the exception showing that

> Cursor Index Out of Bounds Exception: Index -1 requested with size 0

Here is my code

```
SQLiteDatabase db=openOrCreateDatabase("train",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
Cursor c1;
String[] table={"tab1","tab2","tab3","tab4"};
int i=0;
do {
   c1 = db.rawQuery("select * from '"+table[i]+"' where name='Triplicane'", null);
i++;    

} while(c1 == null);

int id1=c1.getInt(0);
String nam1=c1.getString(1);
Toast.makeText(fare.this,"ID no:"+id1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
Toast.makeText(fare.this,"name"+nam1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: What happens if the data you're searching is not there in any of the tables? **(i.e.)** when `i` becomes `4 or more`?

Answer (score 10):

So from the beginning. Implicitly, each **Cursor** is positioned before first row so if you want to work with it you need to call

```
cursor.moveToFirst()
```

that moves Cursor to first row if is not empty and then is ready for work. If Cursor is empty simply it returns **false**. So how i mentioned now this method is very handy indicator whether your Cursor is valid or not.

And as my recommendation i suggest you to change your code because i think is broken and it sounds like "spaghetti code"

```
Cursor c = null;
String[] tables = {"tab1", "tab2", "tab3", "tab4"};
for (String table: tables) {
   String query = "select * from '" + table + "' where name = 'Triplicane'";
   c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
   if (c != null) {
      if (c.moveToFirst()) { // if Cursor is not empty
         int id = c.getInt(0);
         String name = c.getString(1);
         Toast.makeText(fare.this, "ID: " + id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
         Toast.makeText(fare.this, "Name: " + name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
      else {
         // Cursor is empty
      }
   }
   else {
      // Cursor is null
   }
}
```

### Notes:

Now i want to tell you some suggestions:

- An usage of parametrized statements is very good practise so in a
  future if you will work with statements, use placeholders in them. Then your statements becomes more human-readable, safer([`SQL Injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)) and faster.
- It's also a very good practise to create static final fields that will hold
  your column names, table names etc. and to use
  [`getColumnIndex(<columnName>)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndex%28java.lang.String%29) method to avoid "typo errors" which are looking for very bad.

Comment: @WarrenFaith thanks now it should be updated. I worked on update.

Answer (score 0):

Your Cursor flag to empty row , On Sqlite cursor pointed to row number -1 , 
then if you use `c.moveNext()` or `c.moveToFirst()` you'll be able to read rows "row by row "

Answer (score 0):

write   `cursor.movetoFirst()` before getting data from cursor.